# How to extract certain length of numbers from a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
description     
1906 RES 330 ML
1906 RES 330ML
RES 335 c/6
RES 332 c/12
```

I want to extract the three consecutive digits of numbers and save it in a new column 'volume'. 
My code is like this:

```
df['volume'] = df['description'].str.extract('([([\d]*[\d]){3,3}?])')
```

EXPECTED RESULTS SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:

```
volume
330
330
335
332
```

However, it gives the results like this:

```
volume
1906
1906
335
332
```

Can anyone help me fix this code? Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be overkill, but if you want to make sure you don't capture numbers that are part of 4 digit numbers, you might use this:

```
df['volume'] = df.description.str.extract(r'(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)', expand=False)    
print(df)

       description volume
0  1906 RES 330 ML    330
1   1906 RES 330ML    330
2      RES 335 c/6    335
3     RES 332 c/12    332
```

Specify `expand=False`, so that matches are returned as one `pd.Series` only.

---

The regex:

- `(?<!\d)` - specifies that anything before a set of 3 digits is something that is not a digit
- `(\d{3})` - matches 3 digits
- `(?!\d)` - specifies that anything after a set of 3 digits is something that is not a digit

Comment: Maybe `r'(?<!\d)(\d{3,3})(?!\d)'`

Comment: why `\d{3,3}` why not just `\d{3}` ?

Comment: @JBone because I'm still relatively inexperienced with regex. Thanks for the correction. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

- not match any number of digits, three times, so delete the `[\d]*`
- not match 3 digits within anything looking like a "word",
  especially not other digits, so use word boundary `\b`
- not allow optional `?`
- not overdo the character set thing `[]`

You do not need to:

- use two capture groups `()`

This regex will find exactly three digits, alone:

```
\b(\d{3})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is 
`\b[\d]{3}\b`

for more information on `\b` see [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)