# replace four digits pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : ['The **ALI**1929 for 90 days but not 77731929 ', 
                                       'For all **ALI**1952  28A 177945 ', 
                                       'But the **ALI**1914 and **ALI**1903 1912',],
                          'ID': [1,2,3]

                         })

Data    ID
0   The **ALI**1929 for 90 days but not 77731929    1
1   For all **ALI**1952 28A 177945                  2
2   But the **ALI**1914 and **ALI**1903 1912        3
```

My dataframe looks like what I have above. My goal is to replace the word `OLDER` with any number at or under `1929` that is associated with `**ALI**`. So `**ALI**1929` would be `**ALI**OLDER` and `ALI**1903` would also be `**ALI**OLDER` but `**ALI**1952` would remain the same. From [How to extract certain length of numbers from a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925169/how-to-extract-certain-length-of-numbers-from-a-string-in-python) I have tried

```
dataframe['older'] = dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)', 'OLDER')
```

But this doesnt work too well for what I want. I would like something like this as output

```
 Data        ID     older
0                 The ALI**OLDER for 90 days but not 77731929
1                 For all ALI**1952 28A 177945
2                 But the ALI**OLDER and ALI**OLDER 1912
```

How do I change my regex `str.replace(r'(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)'` to do so?

Comment: with your regex it will match `1912` too, will the number you want to replace is always precede by `*` ?

Comment: yes, the they are always preceded by `*`

Comment: check [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/TLAPrj/1/) is this what your looking for ?

Comment: that looks exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
(?<=\*)(?:0\d{3}|1[0-8]\d{2}|19[0-2]\d)(?!\d)
```

- `(?<=\*)` - Should be preceded by `*`
- `(?:0\d{3}|1[0-8]\d{2}|19[0-2]\d)`

  - `0\d{3}` - Matches any 4 digit number between `0000 to 0999`
  - `|`  - Alternation
  - `1[0-8]\d{2}` - Matches any 4 digit number between `1000 to 1899`
  - `|`  - Alternation
  - `19[0-2]\d` - Matches any 4 digit number `1900 to 1929`
- `(?!\d)` - Should not be followed by digit

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TLAPrj/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.extractall` and `np.where` with `str.replace`:

```
nums = dataframe['Data'].str.extractall('(?<=\*\*ALI\*\*)(\d+)').astype(int).unstack()

dataframe['older'] = np.where(nums.le(1929).any(axis=1), 
                              dataframe['Data'].str.replace('(?<=\*\*ALI\*\*)(\d+)', 'OLDER'), 
                              dataframe['Data'])
```

**Output**

```
                                            Data  ID                                           older
0  The **ALI**1929 for 90 days but not 77731929    1  The **ALI**OLDER for 90 days but not 77731929 
1               For all **ALI**1952  28A 177945    2                For all **ALI**1952  28A 177945 
2       But the **ALI**1914 and **ALI**1903 1912   3      But the **ALI**OLDER and **ALI**OLDER 1912
```

Comment: this is really close. But it misses `1929`

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the regex should match `**ALI**nnnn` (*nnnn* - 4 digits) and:

- The initial `**` - should be deleted (always).
- `ALI**` - should be left unchanged.
- *nnnn* - should be optionally replaced with `OLDER`.

In this case, complex regex is not necessary.
The whole logic can be contained in a "replacement" function.

Define it as follows:

```
def repl(mtch):
    g1, g2 = mtch.group(1), mtch.group(2)
    return g1 + (g2 if int(g2) > 1929 else 'OLDER')
```

Then use `str.replace` with this function:

```
df.Data = df.Data.str.replace(r'\*\*(ALI\*\*)(\d{4})(?!\d)', repl)
```

Note that I changed also the regex, defining 2 capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe.Data.str.replace(r"(?<=\*ALI[*]{2})1[0-9](?:(?:[0-4][0-9])|5[0-1])\b","OLDER")
Out[364]: 
0    The **ALI**OLDER for 90 days but not 77731929 
1                  For all **ALI**1952  28A 177945 
2        But the **ALI**OLDER and **ALI**OLDER 1912
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

- `(?<=\*ALI[*]{2})` preceeded by `*ALI**
- `1[0-9]` ie 10-19
- `(?:` begin of the outer Non capturing group

  - `(?:[0-4][0-9])` ie 00-49 but not captured
  - `|5[01]` ie 50-51
- `)` end of non- capturing group
- `\b` boundary

Answer (score 0):

define a custome `repl` callable and use it with `str.replace`

```
repl = lambda m: m.group(1) if int(m.group(1)) > 1929 else 'OLDER'
df.Data.str.replace(r'(?<=\*\*ALI\*\*)(\d+)', repl)

Out[662]:
0    The **ALI**OLDER for 90 days but not 77731929
1                  For all **ALI**1952  28A 177945
2        But the **ALI**OLDER and **ALI**OLDER 1912
Name: Data, dtype: object
```